# What is the difference between I wish,I pray, I hope

Tags: word-difference

> I **wish** I get profit in my investment.

vs.

> I **pray** I get profit in my investment.

vs

> I **hope** I get profit in my investment.

Comment: Have you checked a dictionary?  What have you found out? This would likely get nominations for closing, FYI.

Answer (score 1):

- **Wish** - a desire for something to happen/occur *(especially magically)*, a state of sadness for the situation/action/state existing at the moment or in the past *(feeling sorry for the past)*. A desire to do something or a desire for something to be done.
- **Pray** - an eager hope that something will happen *(mostly magically)*. Speaking to God in order to ask for something.
- **Hope** - to want something to happen or to be true. Often a powerful desire or an expectation. Strongly believe that something will happen *(to want it very much)*.

You can find each of these words in the dictionaries.

Note that normally "**wish**" isn't used in future tenses. Instead, the verb "**hope**" is used:

- I **hope** I get a good present for my birthday *(**not** I wish I get...)*

Comment: Isnt wish used for hypothetical situations? But i have sometimes heard it being used with present tenses . And that's what confuses me

Comment: I know that. But sometimes it is also used with present tenses. In that case does it mean the same as pray?

Comment: @user39122 Provide an example.

Comment: The one in the question

Comment: Among your sentences only "**I hope I get**" is correct.

Comment: I think it's "I wish there **were** rain pouring down now" in correct English.

Comment: In English, "wish" usually opens up a past subjunctive form in verb form and either present subjunctive or past subjunctive in nominal form; "pray" always takes a present subjunctive as in the legal wherefore clause: "Wherefore, the defendant prays this court **be** moved to grant this motion."; and "hope" in Modern English usually does not take any subjunctive form, although it can in some rare instances when it almost reaches a wish: "I can only hope that it **be** so"; however, this is very rare, but Shakespeare used to use it often and it was more common in the days of yore.

Comment: We use the **simple past subjunctive** actually, but native speakers have tried to simplify it. As I've written on this forum before, the past subjunctive in modern English looks equivalent to the simple past except for one verb "to be", which is why we are supposed to say, "I wish I **were** a rich man"; "I wish it **were** raining"; "I wish she **were** my girlfriend."

Comment: "I wish I **had** a car": in that sentence, **had** is technically not in the simple past tense indicative, but the simple past subjunctive; however, it looks equivalent to the *had* in "I **had** plenty of time to do it yesterday."

Comment: "If only it *were* raining. O how I wish it *were* raining. O that it *were* raining. I pray that it *be* raining soon. I hope it *will rain* today."

Comment: Nick, It's still Past Simple anyway. Could you provide your answer please, instead of just commenting?

Comment: No, I disagree. It's technically the simple past **subjunctive**, which is different; however, it only differs in the verb "to be" wherein it can NEVER BE "was"; so yes, it looks like the simple past, but with only a minuscule variance. This is a pet peeve of mine with native speakers. When I edit, I eviscerate "was" when a native speaker writes it here because it's bad English grammar. That's the reason why I always write a lengthy answer to a question on here about the subjunctive.

Comment: _[I wish I might have this wish I wish tonight](https://img1.etsystatic.com/137/1/6123119/il_340x270.925273753_pvpd.jpg)._

Comment: That's the present subjunctive use with "wish" as a verb, J.R. Modals like "may/might" and "would" create the present subjunctive after a verbal form of "wish" in Modern English, rather than the plain present subjunctive; however, in nominal form, the present subjunctive would be bared: "It is my wish that I **have** this wish that I wish tonight."

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Alex's (SovereignSun's) answer completely except regarding the subjunctive used with "wishes", and so I'll exposit on the verbal forms used after all three of these. When "wish" is used as a verb, it usually forms a past subjunctive, whether it be talking about the present, future, or past:

> "I wish it **were** raining outside." (not "was"; present 
>   counterfactual)
>
> "I wish it **had** rained yesterday." (past perfect  subjunctive)
>
> "I wish it **would** rain more." (past subjunctive form of "will" used
>   to talk about the future conditional)

When "wish" is in nominal form, it can take both the present subjunctive and the past subjunctive:

> "It is my wish that he **find** true love." (i.e., "I wish he
>   **would** find true love.")
>
> "It is my wish that he **taught** English instead of History. (i.e.,
>   "I wish he **taught** English now instead of History.")

After "pray", it is to be followed by a present subjunctive, but when talking about "prayed", it is followed by a "would" usually:

> "Wherefore, the defendant prays this court **be** moved to grant this
>   motion."
>
> "I pray that God **give** me the strength and courage to get through
>   these trying times."
>
> "Yesterday, I prayed that God **would** have mercy on those who have
>   committed this atrocity."

When using "hope", it is usually used with the indicative in Modern English:

> "I hope he **knows** what he's doing."
>
> "I hope it **will rain** today."

But, when the word "hope" is used, even in Modern English, as though it were a wish, a yen, a longing for something, it can take a present subjunctive; however, present subjunctives were more common with "hope" around the time of Shakespeare; in fact, Shakespeare wrote some of them in his plays:

> "I can only hope that he **find** true love."

I hope this might have helped you out. Again, Alex is 99.99% right above, but I wanted to clarify a punctilio here that we could not agree upon.  Take care and good luck.